# What is this error when doing Plot[ArgMin[Norm[...,p]],...]?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

When doing

```
Plot[ArgMin[Norm[x - {-3, -1, 0, 5}, p], x], {p, 1, 3}]
```

I get this error message:

```
Plot::exclul: {(Abs[-5+x]^p+Abs[x]^p+Abs[1+x]^p+Abs[3+x]^p)-0,(3+x)-0,(1+x)-0,x-0,(-5+x)-0,
 p-0,Im[Abs[-5+x]^p+Abs[x]^p+Abs[1+x]^p+Abs[3+x]^p]-0}
 must be a list of equalities or real-valued functions.
```

The plot itself seems to be OK

[image]

-- although I am not sure because of this error. What caused it?

Comment: What happens if you add `Exclusions -> None`?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Aha the error is gone then. The plot is the same. Could you explain this, in an answer?

Comment: Before anything else: what version and OS is this?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less 11.0.1.0 on Windows 10

Comment: I do not get an error message with v11.3 on a Mac.

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less But you get the same plot? Should the non-smooth point be there?

Comment: I don't have 11.0 anymore, but the plot in 11.1 looks qualitatively the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that seems to have been resolved in version 11.1, and is related to the exclusion detection functionality used by *Mathematica* to detect discontinuities. (The presence of `Abs[]` in the function being analyzed is what triggered the exclusion detection.)

Since you know that the function is continuous in your range of interest, just add `Exclusions -> None`:

```
Plot[ArgMin[Norm[x - {-3, -1, 0, 5}, p], x], {p, 1, 3}, 
     Exclusions -> None]
```